# How should we be handling endless variations of the same question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Two of the tags that I have set to "interesting" on stackoverflow are "perl" and "apache". I have a feeling that it won't be long until I remove the apache tag from that list because 98% of questions with that tag relate to url-rewriting with mod_rewrite. I won't do that with perl anytime soon, but that tag (sometimes) has a similar problem with questions about regular expressions.

These questions are dupes, but slight variations on the same topic. In fact with the apache example, it has become next to impossible to find a dupe because the stream of questions has become so [endless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache).

What would be the best way to deal with questions like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge questions based on whether an accepted answer (on another question) will fix the "duplicate" as well, rather than just on question text.

Merged questions could appear in an accordion style control with the parent being the highest repped question at the time of the merge (an children being minimized by default). The Parent and child questions would all be community wiki.

Making duplicates disappear just means that the keywords used in that variation are guaranteed to appear again and again until the system knows that VB = Visual Basic = VB.Net, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement 1-vote duplicate closing
2. Clarify that a question can be closed as an "exact duplicate" if they're similar and the *accepted answer* for another question also answers the question in question.
3. Filter closed questions out of search results by default...

Comment: If it only takes one vote to close a question (for any reason) then the rep required to make that distinction needs to be _much_ higher than 3k. Otherwise questions will be continually flip flopping from closed to open as people have differing opinions on what a duplicate is in certain circumstances.

Comment: Well, since you can only vote once, it'd take a constant stream of people with differing opinions. Ideally, they'd take the time to discuss their differences rather than just trying to duke it out, but i suppose the system could revert to the normal 5-vote system after being closed and opened once...

Answer (score 1):

You could ignore the <kbd>mod-rewrite</kbd> tag, and retag any questions that should have the tag but don't.

Comment: Sure, but how would that help the community? And people searching for advice on their mod_rewrite questions.

Comment: It would help people find questions relating to `mod-rewrite`, so it would therefore help the community.